# Support for Shell.Explorer.2

Tags: windows, com, activex, atl, activexobject

I use the Internet Explorer ActiveX component (Shell.Explorer.2) in my applications and my question is - will Windows discontinue support for this component?
I read that Internet Explorer will not be supported from 06/2022 but I can't find anything if the component will still work?

Comment: Only the desktop app is phased out, but components should stay: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549 see "IE mode" discussions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-supports-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality